# My php code is not working, and as a new php coder I am not sure where my mistake is?

Tags: php, forms, contacts

This is my php code, I am using it to post a contact form from my site to my gmail account. It seems that when it gathers the information, it does not sent it and it keeps the typed information visible on my contact.php page, instead of providing any error

```
 <?php 

    session_start();

    require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $errors = array();

    if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phoneNumber'], $_POST['services'], $_POST['message_area'])) {

        $fields = array(
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'phoneNumber' => $_POST['phoneNumber'],
            'services' => $_POST['services'],
            'message_area' => $_POST['message_area']
        );

        foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
            if(empty($data)) {
                $errors[] = 'The ' . $fields . ' field is required.';
            }
        }

        if(empty($errors)) {

            $mail = new PHPMailer;

            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $mail->Username = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
            $mail->Password = 'xxxxxx';
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
            $mail->Port = 465;

            $mail->isHTML();

            $mail->Subject = 'Message from The Rejuviner';
            $mail->Body = 'From: <br /> Name: ' . $fields['name'] . '<br /> Email:' . $fields['email'] . '<br /> Phone Number:' . $fields['phoneNumber'] . '<br /> Services:' . $fields['services'] . '<br /> <p>' . $fields['message_area'] . '</p>';

            $mail->FromName = 'Contact';

            $mail->AddReplyTo($fields['email'], $fields['name']);

            $mail->AddAddress('lilidinova@gmail.com', 'Lily Kostadinova');

            if($mail->send()) {
                header('Location: thanks.php');
                die();
            }
            else {
                $errors[] = 'Sorry, could not send email. Try again later.';    
            }
        }

    }   
        else {
        $errors[] = 'Something went wrong.';    
    }

    $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
    $_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;

    header('Location: contact_form.php');

    ?>
```

I can also post the other main php document which contains the html form elements, if this helps?

Comment: Disable the redirects temporarily and debug the issue on that very page

Comment: Make sure your actually register to connect to gmail via smtp.gmail.com becuase google security features to prohibit unauthorized access

Comment: So I did have an additional question, I did set up a separate email on godaddy "info@therejuviner.com" and then I added it to my gmail account. Does this mean that I have to update the code with this new email account in my php? For example: changing the Host, Username and Password?